# Input sanitizaton without using mysqli_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, sql, regex

I want to strip user input of SQL executable statements, but the way the codebase is I don't want to establish a DB connection which mysqli_real_escape_string(connection, string) requires.

What is an elegant regex/replace one-liner to sanitize the strings?

```
<?php
$naughty = array("\\", "{", "}", ")", "(", "[", "]", "\"", ";", ":", ">", "&");
$sanitized = str_replace($naughty, " ", $input_string);
?>
```

---UPDATE----
Example solution. Thanks for the input guys.

```
<?PHP 
      $testsql = "';\"\\ bork bork bork %A 0x33\n";
      echo $testsql;
     /* $translate = array("0x" => "[HEX]",  ";" => "[SEMICOLON]", "'" => "[QUOTE]", "%" => "[PERCENT]","\"" => "[DOUBLEQUOTE]",
      "\\" => "[BACKSLASH]" ); */
      $translate = array("0x" => " ",  ";" => " ", "'" => " ", "%" => " ","\"" => " ", "\\" => " ");
      echo "<br>";
      $testsql=strtr($testsql, $translate);
      echo $testsql;
?>
```

Comment: Use a prepared statement with bound parameters and you don't have to worry about it any more.

Comment: If you want to go that route, use a whitelist, not a blacklist. `[^\w\s,\pL]` etc.

Comment: Prepared statement won't work in my use case. Due to project scope I can't change code in the other part of the app that actually does the queries and establishes the connection to the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I definitely agree with the comments and answer that using prepared statements, and not doing this yourself is both smarter, better in many ways and always recommended when you can use them. While you may not have a security problem now, one may suddenly appear in the future; and the risk with prepared statements is just much, much lower. If you can find a workaround for it, do it!

I feel like I have to give that disclaimer, in order to be taken seriously here.

Because, I also believe it's definitely possible to do all the escaping manually; given that the environment is controlled. This is no different than escaping for other formats, such as javascript. Sometimes this is needed. I, for one, once had a need to create a SQL export script with no database available.

To do this correctly, the following must be assumed:

- The input string is UTF-8. You validated this.
- When you execute the mysql string later down the road, the full sql statement is in UTF-8, and so is the connection.
- No crazy stuff is going on with php's [mbstring function overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php).
- You don't trust my untested code, and verify what I'm saying ;)

Why is UTF-8 so important? [Read this article](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)

Given those two points, to emulate mysql_real_escape_string, you must escape the following characters:

```
NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z.
```

Source: [php.net](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

To do this, this should be sufficient:

```
$translate = array(
  "\x00" => '\\0',
  "\n"   => '\\n',
  "\r"   => '\\r',
  "'"    => '\\\'',
  "\""   => '\\"',
  "\x1a" => '\\Z',
);

$output = "'" . strtr($input, $translate) . "'";
```

As you can see, I did still make sure that my output was surrounded by quotes. Without that, this escaping technique (nor `mysqli::real_escape_string`) would not be sufficient.

Alternative techniques I've seen:

- Splitting up every byte, and surrounding it with MySQL's [CHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char) function.
- Base64-encoding the string in PHP, and base64-decoding it with MySQL 5.6's [FROM_BASE64](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64) function.

Comment: If I had the time I would love to sit down with the BNF grammar of SQL and make something more advanced than a simple character replace. http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html  Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot properly escape query data without having a connection, and therefore knowledge of the character set.

Do not try to do this yourself.  Your implementation is bound to be insecure.  You should be using prepared queries to separate the data from the query anyway.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the character set, this stuff is important!

Comment: I don't want it escaped, I just want it non-executable. Also, assume I have no DB connection at the point in the code where I need to do some sanitation. A solution that is character set independent would be nice (assuming a sane standard character set).

Comment: @ChadBrewbaker, You underestimate what you need to do.  There is no character-set-independent solution.  What may be very valid data in one case, may not be in another.  There is also really no such thing as a sane standard character set.  You would have to pick one.